# conditional formatting doesn't affect all desired cells

Tags: linux, libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice Calc on Linux.

In my budget spreadsheet I have set up conditional formatting to color the font of a row that matches the condition, as follows:

```
formula: column (E2:E200)="x", rows A2:D200 become red
formula: column (E2:E200)="e", rows A2:D200 become light blue
formula: column (E2:E200)="p", rows A2:D200 become green
formula: LEFT(B2:B200,3)="IN-" rows A2:A200 bocome bold/blue
```

In the image below you can see that the first three conditions works as expected. But the fourth condition will not change the font color of column B. I have been wrestling with this and searching for ideas to no avail. I have also tried placing the conditions in a different order and even tried having only the 4th condition above by itself with no other conditions. In every instance, column B remains unchanged. I have also tried using FIND or SEARCH instead of LEFT.

[image: screenshot of portion of sheet]

Comment: Try using just `B2` in the formula instead of the range `B2:B200`.  Make sure that B2 is the main selected cell in the range (has the black border around it) when you go to edit the condition.  (The formula will be automatically adjusted for the rest of the range as long as you don't put `$` in front of the letter or number.)

Comment: Lyrl: OK! I tried your example of using just (B2,3)="IN-" rather than B2:B200, and my result was that only column A was formatted. Then I added back the $ ($B2,3)="IN-", and that formatted al four columns, as I've been trying to accomplish. Thank you very much for this suggestion. I'm not sure why the difference of the $; perhaps the version I'm using - 4.4.3.2? I would add a snippet of the corrected effect, but I don't see how to do that this time.

Comment: Be careful with conditional formatting in LibreOffice.  See their bug tracker for a list of the relevant bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @Lyrl said, I did these steps:

1. Tools -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage.  Click Edit, or Add if none exists yet.
2. Condition 1 `Formula is`.  Set the value to `LEFT(B2,3)="IN-"`.  Also set the style to apply.  Cell Range (at the bottom) is `B2:B200`.

Now it shows the style correctly.